# UpdateGraph with self referencing entity

Tags: entity-framework, self-referencing-table, graphdiff

I'm using [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) with EF to update state of disconnected objects acquired from a REST Service.

It's working rather well from now but I got a problem with self referencing entities.

Entities :

```
public class Foo {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public Foo() {
        Bars = new HashSet<Bar>();
    }
}

public class Bar {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Children { get; set; }

    public Bar() {
        Children = new HashSet<Bar>();
    }
}
```

UpdateGraph call :

```
DataContext.UpdateGraph(entity, map => map
    .OwnedCollection(e => e.Bars,
        with => with.OwnedCollection(b => b.Children)
    )
);
```

Well this last graph call only updates 1 level of recursivity. How would I go to update no mater how deep the recursion is ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add/update child entities when updating a parent entity in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef)

Comment: It's been 9 years and I moved away from .NET and EF a long while ago. Though this doesn't seem to be the same question as this one is talking about recursively updating children.

Comment: Sorry for the automatically created unintentional question - the comment should be read as  [“Possible duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/the-auto-comment-does-this-answer-your-question-generated-when-voting-to-clos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphDiff currently doesn't support mapping of recursive relationships of non-predetermined depth via the fluent API. Also the new attribute based mapping will throw an exception because of a circular graph. So I'm afraid you can't map this right now, but I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff/issues/106) and will have a look if adding support for this is possible.

Comment: Thanks, will eventually check code and submit a PR on this if I can find some time.