# What is the proper way to update child entities in EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There has to be a better way to handle child Saving/Updating in EF 6. Surely this duplication is just a failure on my part.

Entity

```
public partial class MyParentType
{
    public MyParentType()
    {
        this.children = new HashSet<child>();
    }

    public int parentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<child> children { get; set; }
}
```

Add/Update

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IErrorLogger _logger;
    private readonly CorporateEntities _context;

    public MyRepository(IErrorLogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = new CorporateEntities();
    }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<MyParentType> parents)
    {
        try
        {
            Add(parents.Where(x => x.parentID == 0));
            var updatedData = parents.Where(x => x.parentID != 0);
            foreach (var parent in updatedData)
            {
                var original = _context.MyParentTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.parentID == parent.parentID);
                _context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(parent);
                UpdateChildren(parent);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
        }
    }

    public void Add(IEnumerable<MyParentType> parents)
    {
        if (parents == null)
            return;
        try
        {
            _context.MyParentTypes.AddRange(parents);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            _logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateChildren(MyParentType parent)
    {
        try
        {
            AddChildren(parent.children.Where(x => x.childID == 0));
            var updatedData = parent.children.Where(x => x.childID != 0);
            foreach (var child in updatedData)
            {
                var original = _context.children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.childID == child.childID);
                _context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(child);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            _logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
        }
    }

    private void AddChildren(IEnumerable<child> references)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.children.AddRange(references);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            _logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

I feel like I shouldn't have to duplicate this or write a generic method to handle both cases. Did I miss something in the EF docuemtation where I can update a child entity with the parent one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/update child entities when updating a parent entity in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you use [GraphDiff](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/). With this [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/) your `Update` method would be as I show below:

```
 public void Update(IEnumerable<MyParentType> parents)
 {
   try
   {
       Add(parents.Where(x => x.parentID == 0));
       var updatedData = parents.Where(x => x.parentID != 0);
       foreach (var parent in updatedData)
       {
          _context.UpdateGraph(parent, map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.children));   
       }
       _context.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
     _logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
   }
}
```

This way you don't need to worry about manage the children's states.

If you don't want to use GraphDiff, then you need to manage the state of the children manually:

```
 public void Update(IEnumerable<MyParentType> parents)
 {
   try
   {
       foreach (var parent in parents)
       {
         if(parent.Id==0)
         {
          _context.MyParentTypes.Add(parent);
         }
         else
         { 
            //When you change the state to Modified all the scalar properties of the entity will be marked as modified
           _context.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;

            foreach(var child in parent.children)
            {
               context.Entry(child).State =child.Id>0? EntityState.Modified:EntityState.Added;  
            }
         }
       }

       _context.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
     _logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
   }
}
```

Comment: With GraphDiff, you still explicitly graph each child (see line 9 of your code)?

Comment: Also, Is lodging supposed to be child?

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to manage the state of  each child by yourself, also, GraphDiff lets you update related entities  at deeper levels of the graph. For example if `child`  have a collection of another entity (`ICollection<AnotherEntity> AnotherEntities`), then you could update the graph this way:`context.UpdateGraph(parent, 
    map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.children, 
        with => with.OwnedCollection(c => c.AnotherEntities)));`

Comment: Fair enough, it seems like a decent trade off

Comment: About the second, it was a typo error, I have already fixed, thanks

Comment: @octavioccl Your manual method does not handle children which have been deleted ?

Comment: GraffDiff is still not supported for EF core. 
But [EF-Core-Simple-Graph-Update](https://github.com/WahidBitar/EF-Core-Simple-Graph-Update) works for me