# Entity Framework: List of own modeltype deletes other entries

Tags: entity-framework, list

we have built a REST API service which we currently use in an Android- and iOS application. To store the data we use Entity Framework. Within this API you are able to create an account and with that you are also able to add other users as your friends. We are having problems adding other users as friends.

**This is the scenario:**
User A adds User B as a friend, this works. 
User C adds User B as a friend, this works, although now User A has lost User B from his friendslist.

**The problem:**
The problem here is that User A lost User B as a friend and this is our problem which we are trying to solve. We have absolutely no idea why or even how User A loses User B as his friend from his friendslist. We are all very new with Entity Framework and with that said we have very little experience with it.

**Where we are today:** 
We have a Model for a `User` and within this Model we have a `List<User> friends` which contains other users. The idea is to add users to this list. For clarification: The type User of the List is **the same** as the the entire Class User which contains this list. In other words we are adding other users to our own list of users. In the second code sample below we retrieve a user by it's username:

`User friend = db.Users.Single(i => i.userName == newFriend.userName);`.

The current User

`User user = db.Users.Include("Friends").Single(i => i.userName == currentUser);`

is adding the User `friend` to his own list of friends.

This is the Model for a User:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<Vacation> vacations { get; set; }
    public List<User> friends { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code to add a user as a friend:

```
using (var db = new ProjectDbContext())
{
    User friend = db.Users.Single(i => i.userName == newFriend.userName);
    User user = db.Users.Include("Friends").Single(i => i.userName == currentUser);

    if (friend != user)
    {
        if (!user.friends.Contains(friend))
        {
            user.friends.Add(friend);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok("Friend added.");
        }
        else
            return BadRequest("Friend already exists.");
    }
    else
        return BadRequest("You cannot add yourself as a friend.");
}
```

I hope i explained this with enough detail that someone is able to help us with this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share DB structure ?

Comment: Do you mean like this?

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [userName]  NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [firstName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [lastName]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [email]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [User_id]   INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Users_User_id] FOREIGN KEY ([User_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([id])
);`

Comment: Child collections are tricky in EF. See this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved our issue with a simple line of code which goes into the DBcontext-file. We did override the function `OnModelCreating` and added a line of code which enables many-to-many relations when using foreign keys of the same model. This is the code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.friends).WithMany(); 
}
```