# Entity Framework 6 - ASP.Net MVC - Detect changed collections on post back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
Class Student 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

The scenario goes like this:

1. Page is loaded to client with Student **using entity framework(EF) 6**
2. List of Locations edited by client by removing one, but another added
3. Student is posted back to save and auto-bound to the model

I could attach Student back to the EF context using:

```
context.Entry(Student).Attach();
```

The problem is that EF will not detect the changes in Locations. I have to:

1. Save Locations in a **new Locations list**
2. Set **Student.Locations** = null;
3. Then attach Student to the **DbContext**
4. Loop through all **Student.Locations** and **Remove** each one
5. Loop through all the **new Locations list** that I saved, pull the location from the database, then **Add** to Student
6. Finally **Save**

What a pain. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, that's a pain point that has been noted. https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864 You will need to implement code like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef

Answer (score 0):

You probably better implement different actions independently: 
IE: one action for adding a location and another action for removing an existing action.

Then you can just call them with ajax to keep user interactivity.

Comment: It's more efficient to let the user make changes, then save at the end. It's the whole concept of having these changes detected that's the issue.

Comment: It really depends on your view of things, but i think separating actions is better in the context of a web app. say for example user made lots of changes and then got a browser crash he will lose all changes. If every change was commited whenver made he will lose at most the last change. Just a quick example to illustrate why this approach might be better

Comment: Good point. Then that would mean keeping the data in session whilst it's being edited so EF can track everything.

Comment: That's another way to do things. but i wouldn't recommend it