# update entity that include child entities (Update, Delete) entity frame work 5 C#

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have one entity include other child entities
    parent > reservation
    reservation > hotel > room
    reservation > transfer > car
I am making all change to copy of reservation as Session variable
After I want to save change to data base copy..

all simple attribute is change but (inside entities not effected)
The problem is one hotel is removed but database dose not changed

```
Res = session["res"];
var record = db.Reservations.Where(d => d.ID == Res.ID).FirstOrDefault();
db.Entry(record).CurrentValues.SetValues(Res);
```

Comment: You're going to have to do something like this for the child records: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef

Comment: db.SaveChanges(); is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to:

```
db.Entry(record).state = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```