# EF Core 5 - Updating an entity in many-to-many relation throws "Violation of PRIMARY KEY" error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I am working with [.NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five) and using [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) and `MSSQL` for database.

I have 2 classes that have many to many relationship between them. Those were migrated from models to DB.
[example of DB tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rshfz.png)

Migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "TournamentUser",
            columns: table => new
            {
                TournamentsId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                UsersId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_TournamentUser", x => new { x.TournamentsId, x.UsersId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_TournamentUser_Tournaments_TournamentsId",
                    column: x => x.TournamentsId,
                    principalTable: "Tournaments",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_TournamentUser_Users_UsersId",
                    column: x => x.UsersId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

Models:

```
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MaxPlayers { get; set; }
    public int PlayersCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public bool IsStarted { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnded { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(15)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }
}
```

So as I try to update Tournaments model

```cs
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult<Tournament>> Put([FromBody] Tournament tournament)
{
    _context.Tournaments.Update(tournament);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTournament), new { id = tournament.Id }, tournament);
}
```

I get this error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of
> PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TournamentUser'. Cannot insert duplicate
> key in object 'dbo.TournamentUser'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1).

What could be possible solutions for this? I would like to keep my many to many table udpated as `Tournament's User` can be removed or added each time I update `Tournament`.

**EDIT:**
Following shows the tournament object data -

[image: Example of updatable tournament object]

Comment: can you show your Tournament tournament object that you are trying to update, pls? Does it include Users?

Comment: I attached it at the end of a post. It does include user, that has already been inserted in the previous update action. Somehow, UPDATING tournament forces to INSERT all user-tournament relation, even though it already has one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735368/updating-related-data-with-entity-framework-core/47126068)

I have modified the code a bit, since originally it was removing users from table and I got the result I wanted

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Tournament>> Put([FromBody] Tournament tournament)
    {
        var _tournament = _context.Tournaments.Include(t => t.Users).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == tournament.Id);
        _context.Entry(_tournament).CurrentValues.SetValues(tournament);
        var _users = _tournament.Users.ToList();
        // Adds new Users
        foreach (var tournamentUser in tournament.Users)
        {
            if (_users.All(i => i.Id != tournamentUser.Id))
            {
                _tournament.Users.Add(tournamentUser);
            }
        }
        // Removes old Users
        foreach (var tournamentUser in _users)
        {
            if (tournament.Users.FirstOrDefault(tu => tu.Id == tournamentUser.Id) == null)
            {
                _tournament.Users.Remove(tournamentUser);
            }
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTournament), new { id = tournament.Id }, tournament);
    }
```

Not sure if it's not over complex but it works

Comment: Your post mentions nothing about adding/removing users to/from the related list (i.e. updating the user list itself, not the entities in that list). You should make it clear in the post what you are trying to achieve, what is your result are you expecting.

Comment: How come did I not mention it? It is obviously stated in post: "What could be possible solutions for this? I would like to keep my many to many table udpated as Tournament's User can be removed or added each time I update Tournament."

Comment: That could be a lot more simplified represent your issue. LOL. Or, may be its my mistake that I failed to understand what to you tried to express.

Comment: damn, bro, that's crazy

Answer (score 4):

**The Solution:**

To update the `Tournament` entity *only*, use the following approach -

```cs
_context.Entry(tournament).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**The Explanation:**

1. The `Update()` method marks the entity as `Modified` if it has an `Id` (auto generated primary key) value, and as `Added` if it doesn't have an `Id` value. Same is true for any related entities if you call the method with an entity graph (entity with related entities). Then on the next `SaveChanges()` call, EF generates update and/or insert command for the entity (or entities) based on whether they are marked as `Modified` or `Added`. The point is - *the `Update()` method does not only update an entity, it can insert new entities too*.
2. In your case, looking at the models, EF can tell `Tournament` and `User` are in a many-to-many relationship, and there is a joining entity `TournamentUser` at database level. But since you are receiving the entity graph from outside, they are not tracked by EF and it cannot tell whether the `TournamentUser` entities for this tournament and the related users already exist in database or not.
3. As you are calling the `Update()` method with the entity graph, the tournament, the related users, and the joining entity relating them (`TournamentUser`) all becomes subject for update operation. And EF tries to create the joining entity just like it would create/insert a new entity without an `Id` value.
4. EF generates insert command for a `TournamentUser` entity and update commands for `Tournament` and `User` entities. But at database level, since the `TournamentUser` link already exists you get the `Violation of PRIMARY KEY` error.

The -

```cs
_context.Entry(tournament).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

suggested above explicitly marks *only* the tournament as `Modified`. Therefore, EF doesn't bother to look at any related entities, or to *infer* any relationship, and only an update command is generated for the tournament.

Comment: I have already figured out how to update tournament only, but my main goal is to update tournament and nested entity. As I have provided sample of database, there are 3 tables, although I have 2 models, and I would like to keep it that way hoping for entity framework to manage 3rd table. Is that possible?

Comment: Thank for the help, I've managed to find a solution, posted it below.

Comment: thank you atiyar for the solution and very detailed explanation. This solution is what I wanted, I only wanted to update the entity itself just like old days when a simple json data for the entity only is provided

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove users from your torment object if you want to update tournment.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<Tournament>> Put([FromBody] Tournament tournament)
    {
         tournament.Users=null;
        _context.Tournaments.Update(tournament);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
.....
   
    }
```

Or if you want to add  an user to your tournament

```
var existing= _context
              .Tournaments
              .Include(u=>u.Users)
              .FirstOrDefault(t=> t.Id== tournament.Id);

if(existing==null) return ...error

if( existing.Users==null) existing.User=new List<User>();

if( existing.Users.Any(u=>u.Id=tournment.User.Id) return ...error

existing.Users.Add(tournment.User);
_context.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

It looks ackward but  you are paying for not adding many-to-many relantionship table explicitly. If you use UserTournment table code will be shorter.

You can try this. I never tried it. Let me know if it works:

```
var existing = _context
              .Tournaments
              .Include(u=>u.Users)
              .FirstOrDefault(t=> t.Id== tournament.Id);

if(existing==null) return ...error

_context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(tournment);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But then it wouldn't add tournament-user relation into database

Comment: This is definitely not the thing I am asking for