# Is there any lib that adds/updates child entities when updating a parent entity in Entity Framework Core, without write a lot of manual code?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I Would like to do update child entities when updating parent entity.

Most solutions, like "[How to add/update child entities when updating a parent entity in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef)", handle this issue manually writing a lot of code for each case.

I know that there is some tools like "Trackable Entities" that track changes and updates child entities based on the parent entity. but it is not compatible with "Core" version. (I don't want to use entire .net framework)

Is there any tool or easier way to do this task?

Comment: You can take a look at [Detached.EntityFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/entityframeworkcore-detached). I personally haven't tried it, so can't share opinion about its usefulness.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, need to add or update child entity while inserting parent entity

Comment: There is no news about this..  I'm still writing code manually