# Disconnected Entity: Identifying Children To Be Deleted

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity with a list of children. When I send an update request from the front-end, I use the child object's ID to determine whether to set the object's state to modified or added (ID = 0 means added),

For a child whose state needs to be set to deleted, I would prefer not to have to do an additional call to the db to get the existing children and compare the two lists.

One approach I was considering is for the front-end to send a list of child IDs to be deleted with the object, something like:

```
public class Movie
{
    String title;
    List<Actor> actors;

}

public class Actor
{
    int id;
    String name;

}

public class MovieUpdateRequest
{
    Movie movie;
    int[] actorsToBeDeleted; //array of movie Ids to be deleted
}
```

Another possibility I considered would be to have a deletion flag in the Actor class that isn't mapped to the db, which could be set by the front-end.

```
public class Actor
{
    int id;
    String name;

    [NotMapped]
    Boolean toBeDeleted;

}
```

Either approach would provide a way of identifying which Actor objects needs their state to be set to deleted. My question is is there a better or more common approach to take for this basic operation.

Comment: EF designers left all operations (basic or not) on disconnected graphs for the developers using EF. So no, there is no common standard out of the box approach.

Comment: [Data Points - Handling the State of Disconnected Entities in EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt694083) post by  Julie Lerman explains one possible approach (similar to your second approach, but not relying on Id for add/update determination).

Comment: Some other options are to update your states manually, e.g. as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef/27177623#27177623) or use a library such as [GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff) (seems quite popular but not tried it myself). I understand they're looking to improve the handling in EF Core but no plans to put it in EF6.

Comment: If you really want to reduce the number of queries, and you're running SQL Server, you might want to bulk load the children into a temp table, or use a TVP or pass them as JSON, and then MERGE them in a single statement.