# List of Child model not updating when parent is updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these models:

```
public class GroupSetCollection {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<GroupSet> GroupSets { get; set; }
}

public class GroupSet {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<Group> Groups{ get; set; } 
}
```

Whenever I update the `GroupSetCollection` all the properties are updated except for the `GroupSets`. When I manually call the update on the `GroupSet` it gives me the following error.

> Attaching an entity of type 'GroupSet' failed because another entity of the >same type already has the same primary key value for child.`

Below is the method I'm using to update the entities.
It fails at the `GroupSet` update and works fine on the `GroupSetCollection` update.

```
public void UpdateGroupSetCollection(GroupSetVM groupSetCollection)
        {
            _GroupSetCollectionService.Update(VMToEntity(groupSetCollection));
            _GroupSet.Update(groupSetCollection.GroupSets);

        }
```

Comment: If `List<GroupSet> GroupSets` are related with the `GroupSetCollection`, it isn't necessary update the entities individualy. So, when `GroupSetCollection` is updated, its entities related are also updated. Maybe adding `public virtual List<GroupSet> GroupSets {get; set;}` will fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef

Comment: @JesusPocoata That's it! They weren't set to virtual that was my issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to load related entities, one of them is add the word `virtual` to the related entity.

So, you final class will be:

```
public class GroupSetCollection {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<GroupSet> GroupSets { get; set; }
}
```

You could also read about [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) from the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JesusPocoata for helping my figure out the issue.

I hadn't set the `List<GroupSet>` to `virtual` once that was done it worked perfectly.