# Add or Update child entities when updating a parent entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-3.1

In a new project we are using Entity Framework Core instead of EntityFramework 6.2.0. Works good but it causes a problem when updating a parents children while also inserting new children.

Example:

Current model:

```
public class Profile
{

    public Profile()
    {
        Interests = new List<Interest>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }

}

public class Interest
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Code to add or update children in Entity Framework, worked fine in EntityFramework 6.2.0

```
//Interests
//Delete children
foreach (var existingChild in dbProfile.Interests.ToList())
{
    if (!profile.Interests.Any(c => c.Name == existingChild.Name))
        db.Interests.Remove(existingChild);
}

//Update and Insert children
foreach (var childModel in profile.Interests)
{
    var existingChild = dbProfile.Interests
        .Where(c => c.Name == childModel.Name)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (existingChild != null)
    {
        // Update child
        childModel.Id = existingChild.Id;
        db.Entry(existingChild).CurrentValues.SetValues(childModel);
    }
    else
    {
        // Insert child
        var newChild = new Interest
        {
            Name = childModel.Name,
        };
        dbProfile.Interests.Add(newChild);
    }
}
```

Code is based on this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27177623/3850405

When using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.6` this happens:

A new Interest is added with `Id 0` as expected.

[image]

However if an update occurs and the following code is ran:

```
db.Entry(existingChild).CurrentValues.SetValues(childModel);
```

Every new object with `Id 0` has their `Id` set to `-2147482197`. This happens even though nothing is set for the parent object, only a single child object. Why does this happen? Has something replaced the above method in EF Core?

[image]

I can solve this by removing `db.Entry(existingChild).CurrentValues.SetValues(childModel);` and replace it with `childModel.Name = existingChild.Name;`. But if the object had 20 or more properties I would not like to manually map them one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the following NuGets from `2.2.6` to `3.1.0` and then everything started working normally:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Comment: @Holger I must wait 48 hours before I can do that. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/