# EntityFramework error when saving record with list of child records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.NET Core we're using EF Core. When saving a record that has a list of child records we get the following error:

The instance of entity type `Child` cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

Step-by-step:
1. fetch record from the controller and pass it to the view (view has a )
2. update some properties via the html form
3. click save
4. catch model passed in the controller Save method. Get the original item from DB and save changes (as made via the form)
5. call update/save in the repository

Simplified code below:

```cs
// Get the record from the database
var record = _dbContext.Parents
    .Include(x => p.SomeOtherObject)
    .Include(x => x.ListChildren)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdParent == id);

// then we do some changes to Parent and ListChildren
// we do not do any changes to SomeOtherObject!!!

// save changes
_dbContext.Update(record);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

// definition of entities
public class Parent
{
    public int IdParent { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}

    public int IdSomeOtherObject { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdSomeOtherObject")]
    public virtual SomeOtherObject SomeOtherObject { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child> ListChildren { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int IdChild { get; set; }
    public int IdParent { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherObject
{
    public int IdSomeOtherObject { get; set; }
    public string PropertiesBlahBla { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I know that we can add `.AsNoTracking()` to the `Get` operation, but then the problem is that when saving `Parent` EntityFramework will perform and `UPDATE` SQL statement even for the `SomeOtherObject` (that was not changed in any way) and that is not acceptable for our data/input scenario.

Is there any other way to get pass this error?

Comment: Perhaps give this a try.   Remove `update(record);`, then `_dbContext.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Detached;`   then make changes to `record`.   Then `_dbContext.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified; _dbContext.savechanges();`

Comment: Get and Update of the record is done in repository and changes are done in controller. Should I add `...Detached` before returning the record to the controller, then make changes in controller and then add `...Modified` in the repository where I update the record ?

Comment: OK, I tried this and the record `Parent` get's saved with no error, but any changes in `ListChildren` do not get saved

Comment: Try retrieving children and do the `Detached`, then modify them and then  set state to `Modified'.  Then call `saveChanges`.

Comment: @Allen King: thank you for your comments. The problem was in the way I was updating child lists (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `_dbContext.Update(record);`. Your entities should already be tracked, so changes should be saved.

As [`Update` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-3.1) state:

> Begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity using the Modified state by default

So it seems that in this scenario it is not needed.

**UPD**

During discussions in chat was discovered that child tracked collection was substituted like this:

```
record.ListChildren = someModel.ListChildren.Where(...).ToList()
```

Which resulted in addition of elements with already tracked ids. So the `ListChildren` should be updated with saving already tracked items like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef/27177623#27177623).

Comment: this is the complete error: 'The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

Comment: @TheMixy Is your db context scoped? Also check that `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` is empty before the call.

Comment: @TheMixy Also can you add minimal, reproducible Example?

Comment: in `startup.cs` we're using `services.AddScoped<xyz, xyz>();` to add the service/repository

Comment: when trying to inspect `context.ChangeTracker.Entries();` it returns the same error as my original question above

Comment: @TheMixy if you try to access it before fetching `record` it means that error is somewhere outside(before) provided code.

Comment: the entire solution/project is really big so it's hard to prepare a minimal, reproducible example, especially without the DB connection ... I will add some additional info to my code sample above

Comment: I tried to access it (context.ChangeTracker.Entries()) after Get and before Update/SaveChanges

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214605/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-themixy).