# How to do EntityFramework InsertOrUpdateOrDelete

Tags: entity-framework

Data outside a certain set of records will be deleted, only data added or updated will remain. How do I do this entity framework

**Sample**

```
public void MultipleAddOrUpdateDifferenceDelete(Expression<Func<DataClass, bool>> expression)
        {
            _context.Entry(_context).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            _context.DataClass.Where(expression);
            _context.Entry(_context).State = EntityState.Added;
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question or your provided code what you are trying to accomplish, and the code example doesn't make any sense. As a general rule methods should be structured to provide a specifc, single purpose. As soon as you start merging concerns with "Or" (I.e. Add OR Update OR Delete) You are bound to be making complex, brittle code.

Comment: I want the data in my table to be always the same as the database. I want the data I deleted, added, or updated from the table to be automatically synchronized with the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add/update child entities when updating a parent entity in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef)