# EF Core: Disconnected delete from a large child collection with pagination

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

My question is based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27177623/4522506) but with the added complexity of **pagination**.

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.Children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Say the Children collection has 1000 records:

{ 1, 2, 3, ... 998, 999, 1000 }

```
public Parent Get(int parentId, int childrenPageSize)
{
    var existingParent = _dbContext.Parents
    .Where(p => p.Id == parentId)
    .Include(p => p.Children.Take(childrenPageSize))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

With pagination, we only take the first 10 children:

{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }

The user then edits the Parent object in the front-end application, and deletes 2 children in the collection, and clicks Save to Update the parent:

{ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }

I use Update method in the repository class

```
public void Update(UpdateParentModel model)
{
    var existingParent = _dbContext.Parents
    .Where(p => p.Id == model.Id)
    .Include(p => p.Children)
    .SingleOrDefault();

    // Delete children
    foreach (var existingChild in existingParent.Children.ToList())
    {
        if (!model.Children.Any(c => c.Id == existingChild.Id))
            _dbContext.Children.Remove(existingChild);
    }
}
```

**Question**: When Entity Framework loads the existingParent, it eager loads the entire collection of 1000 children. The model argument contains a collection of 8 children as two were deleted. How can I tell Entity Framework to remove only the 2 children that were deleted?

**Note**: I want to avoid using ExecuteDelete, RawSQL, or Stored Procedures. I need to be able to call _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdateParentModel` should contain a property of `IEnumerable<int>` that represents the IDs of `Child` objects to delete.  You can then attach a new `Child` object as deleted with only the ID value set for each ID value in that enumerable property, avoiding the need to load anything from the database.

The models you use for your operations do not need to match the entity or entities they’re acting upon.  Package the data in the most useful/efficient fashion.

```
foreach( var childId in model.RemovedChildIDs )
{
    var entry = dbContext.Attach( new Child
    {
        Id = childId,
    } );

    entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
}

…

dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: thank you. I'm assuming its the same solution for Update and Insert? Just keep a separate collection on the front end of those objects and send them to the backend separately from the Parent model?

Comment: If you're inserting a new Parent then all the children would be new objects so there's no change in state to track (at least based on what you've shown us), but if you're adding and removing children to/from a parent with the same request then yes, you could use a separate collection that contains the new children entities

Answer (score 0):

If you had the complete set in both cases then it could determine which ones to remove, but you have different sets, one is a paginated set and one is a complete one. Given 8 items, EF has no way of knowing what the original 10 was, unless you tell it. One option is to give it the page size and page number, assuming you can change the "page" of the child view:

```
public void Update(UpdateParentModel model, int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10)
{
    var existingParent = _dbContext.Parents
    .Where(p => p.Id == model.Id)
    .Include(p => p.Children
        .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
        .Skip((pageNumber-1)*pageSize)
        .Take(PageSize)
        .ToList())
    .SingleOrDefault();


    var existingChildrenIds = existingParent.Children.Select(x => x.Id);
    var updatedChildrenIds = model.Children.Select(x => x.Id);
    var childrenIdsToRemove = existingChildrenIds.Except(updatedChildrenIds);

    if (childrenIdsToRemove.Any())
    {
        childrenToRemove = existingParent.Children
            .Where(x => childrenIdsToRemove.Any(x.Id))
            .ToList();
        foreach(var child in childrenToRemove)
            existingParent.Children.Remove(child);
    }     
}
```

This also avoids iterating over 1000 (or in this case 10) children to see if any need to be removed. Over 10 items it won't make much of a difference, but over larger sets it can.

One caveat here is that when using 'Skip' & 'Take' you should always be including an `OrderBy` clause to ensure that results for pagination are predictable and repeatable. Without it, larger sets of data could come back in different or unpredictable order based on database index paging.

Comment: We've thought about this solution as well, but the problem is that our front-end angular app will need to keep track of the pagination, and which page the children were deleted on. For example, in the first 10 items on page 1, user deleted a child. Then clicked next in the paginator, which now displays items 11-20, and he deletes a child there. And then clicks Last, which takes the user to the last set of children 990-1000, and deletes an item there. So the collection sent to the server would be containing { 1 - 20, 990 - 1000 } with 3 items missing, and difficult to send page number info.

Comment: Yes, that would get ugly. Even if you accumulate the deletes and make calls grouped by page # the rows were selected to be deleted, that would have to execute in reverse page order (I.e. all deletes from pg 100, then pg 2 then pg 1) or selecting paged entries in the entity would be affected. I'd be leaning for Moha's suggestion. Though to be safe check the `context.Children.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == childId)` local cache before attempting to attach a child in case the context happens to be tracking one. Assuming you are using server-side pagination you will need to track Is to delete.